# Groovy: parametrized link tag

Tags: grails, groovy, controller

I have the following gsp page:

```
<g:def var="incidentMngmntId" value="${incidentMngmntInstance?.id}"/>
<g:link controller="ticketMngmnt" 
        action="list" params="[incidentMngmntId : incidentMngmntId]"
        id="${incidentMngmntInstance?.id}"> Tickets
</g:link>
```

The generated URL is as follows

```
http://localhost:8080/smtool/ticketMngmnt/list/94
```

Which is fact is not what is intended.
(My intention is to generate a pair var=value as get or post.)

At the ticketMngmnt controller I have the following code which 
cannot catch the value of the parameter.

```
 def list = {       
    def incidentMngmntId = params.incidentMngmntId
    println "params.incidentMngmntId " + incidentMngmntId

    ...
}
```

and of course it is always printing

```
params.incidentMngmntId null
```

The question is twofold:
First, is possible at the gsp level to generate a link of the form
http://localhost:8080/smtool/ticketMngmnt/list?incidentMngmntId=94
(or a to give the par var=value as post)

Second, if not -the link remains as **http://localhost:8080/smtool/ticketMngmnt/list/94** -
then the question is how to read the value **94** at the controller.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Luis

PS: BTW, the value **94** is correct

Comment: I got it running now. I would like to close this question because it is no more relevant.

Comment: If you got it running please 'answer' your question and mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code is correct as it is.
I just restarted the server and that was.

The only think to be changed is the unnecessary id at the link

```
<g:def var="incidentMngmntId" value="${incidentMngmntInstance?.id}"/>
<g:link controller="ticketMngmnt" 
    action="list" params="[incidentMngmntId : incidentMngmntId]">
    Tickets
</g:link>
```

Sorry.